# Multiple Windows Messenger Users Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-live-messenger

I am trying out Windows 8 to see if I want to use it on my main computer. In Windows 8 I have my domain user account linked to my personal outook.com Live account. This is great for everything except Windows Live Messenger. I need to have my domain messenger account accessible. Is there a way to sign into multiple Messenger accounts on Windows 8, or at least sign into a different account without affecting every other app?

Thanks!
Kurt

Comment: Windows Live Messenger is being discontinued.  Have you tried this behavior with the desktop Skype client?

Answer (score 1):

Via the website outlook.com you can chat in the browser.
If you open new sessions of internet explorer (normal/in private/metro) and other browsers. You have plenty of different chat sessions.

Don't forget that Microsoft announced that it will drop Windows Live Messenger and promote Skype now.
I suggest you switch to Skype and take over your accounts.